magic xpa with docker
I want to run Magic xpa(-low code tool) with Docker
That is, instead of installing the environment on my computer,
I want to do it with Dockerfile/Dockercompose
Can someone tell me how to do this step by step?

One of Docker's main goals is that a container is isolated from the host system: the host system can't directly run the tools in a container, and the container can't see the source code or other artifacts on the host.  This can make it tricky to use a container for a development tool, where your OS package manager can generally easily install and uninstall it directly on the host.
